# How to await browser until data gets populated in a dropdown box without using delay() in puppeteer?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, jestjs, ui-automation, puppeteer

I tried using {waitUntil:'networkidle2'} to wait till the data gets loaded but it doesn't works. So, i am using a long await delay(time) coz i don't know how long will it take to populate the data to the dropdown box. It is consuming a lot of time. So there must be some way, where browser waits till the dropdown box populates with data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `waitForFunction` function. This will wait until the `<your selector>` element is populated.

```js
await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("<your selector>").options.length');
```

Comment: sorry, the question was not clear. as the data loads randomly from database to the drop down menu, i actually was wondering if there was any way to wait for the loading process !